# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on WordPress Development breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5         16
Users destroyed                                 503          0
Users deleted                                    13          0
Users contacted                                  12          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue         1,357      2,174
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              215        178
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        527        856
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              624      1,091
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               263      9,680
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue            1,766     10,173
Tags merged                                      11          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             6          0
Tag synonyms created                              6          0
Revisions redacted                                3          0
Questions reopened                               35          0
Questions protected                               7        100
Questions migrated                               49          4
Questions flagged⁴                               61      3,713
Questions closed                              3,349      1,175
Question flags handled⁴                         898      2,876
Posts unlocked                                    0         14
Posts undeleted                                  33        244
Posts locked                                      1        487
Posts deleted⁵                                2,058     10,779
Posts bumped                                      0      8,732
Comments undeleted                               13          0
Comments flagged                                  5      3,441
Comments deleted⁶                             1,870      4,813
Comment flags handled                           869      2,577
Answers flagged                                  29      3,385
Answer flags handled                          2,907        507
All comments on a post moved to chat              3          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...